# ordered list not displaying number sequence correctly in php?

Tags: php

Ordered list displays fine on first page but on next page, its also displaying last number from previous page. How to solve this problem?

Here is my full code:

```
<?php
  $sql01 = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM pm";
  $result = mysql_query($sql01, $conn) or trigger_error("SQL", E_USER_ERROR);
  $r = mysql_fetch_row($result);
  $numrows = $r[0];
  $rowsperpage = 3;

  // find out total pages
  $totalpages = ceil($numrows / $rowsperpage);

  // get the current page or set a default

  if (isset($_GET['currentpage']) && is_numeric($_GET['currentpage'])) {
     // cast var as int
     $currentpage = (int) $_GET['currentpage'];
  } 
  else 
  {
     // default page num
     $currentpage = 1;
  } // end if

  // if current page is greater than total pages...  
  if ($currentpage > $totalpages) {    
     // set current page to last page
     $currentpage = $totalpages;
  } // end if

  // if current page is less than first page...   
  if ($currentpage < 1) {
     // set current page to first page
     $currentpage = 1;
  } // end if

  // the offset of the list, based on current page 
  $offset = ($currentpage - 1) * $rowsperpage;

  // get the info from the db 
  // while there are rows to be fetched...
  $sql=mysql_query("select *from pm where send_to='$_GET[name]' limit $offset, $rowsperpage");
  $sql2=mysql_query("select *from pm_reply where send_to='$_GET[name]' limit $offset, $rowsperpage");
  $start_from = $offset + 1;
  echo "<ol start='$start_from'>";
  while($rows=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
     echo"<li>From: <a href='profile.php?name=$rows[send_by]'>$rows[send_by]</a><br><br><a style='text-decoration:none; font-size:14pt;' href='view_pm.php?name=$_GET[name]&pm=$rows[subject]'>$rows[subject]</a></li>"; 
     echo "<hr>";
     echo "<br>";
  }

  while($rows2=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql2)) {
     echo"<li>From: <a href='profile.php?name=$rows2[replied_by]'>$rows2[replied_by]</a><br><br><a style='text-decoration:none; font-size:14pt;' href='view_pm.php?name=$_GET[name]&pm=$rows2[subject]'>$rows2[subject]</a></li>"; 
     echo "<hr>";
     echo "<br>"
  }

  echo "</ol>";
  echo "</div>";
  //End Div Content
```

Comment: Please consider removing those sooooo many extra blank lines to make your code more understandable for others at least.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**pink box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: Lovely [SQL injection attack](http://bobby-tables.com) vulnerabilities. Enjoy having your server pwn3d.